# The content-type is not JSON compatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, oauth-2.0

With the following code Im trying to create a `accessToken` with the simple-oauth2 library in node.
I have the server.js and the app.js files. The problem is that every time I try to call the `getToken` method it returns the following error *The content-type is not JSON compatible*. Im calling the `/token` endpoint with postman where the request´s `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

server.js

```
'use strict';

const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const port = 3000;

module.exports = (cb) => {

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(`Express server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);

    return cb({
        app
    });
});
};
```

app.js

```
const createApplication = require('./server');
const simpleOauthModule = require('simple-oauth2');
require('dotenv').config()

const credentials = {
    client: {
        id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    auth: {
        tokenHost: 'http://localhost:3000/test'
    }
};

createApplication(({ app }) => {

app.post('/token', async (req, res) => {
    const oauth2 = simpleOauthModule.create(credentials);

    var contype = req.headers['content-type']; // <-- application/json

    const tokenConfig = {
        username: "test",
        password: "1234"
    };

    try {
        const result = await oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig); //Error occuress
        const accessToken = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);

        console.log('Access Token: ', accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
    }
});

app.post('/test', async (req, res) => {

});
});
```

Comment: You need to serialize you object in JSON before making the request

Comment: I have tried to use `JSON.stringify(tokenConfig)` before I pas it to the `getToken` method without luck.

Comment: can you console.log tokenconfig before and show the output?